# Better way for handling windows messages?

Tags: winapi, design-patterns, message

I work on some project using C and uses Win32API, using different language or any other libraries such as MFC, GTK, QT .. etc, is not an option.

I'm looking for a good way for handling windows messages/signals/events like :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(msg) {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(wparam) {
                case ID_OK_BUTTON:
                    DoSomething(hwnd);
                    break;
                case ID_FOO_BUTTON:
                    DoFoo(hwnd);
                    break;
                /*
                ....
                It's only getting more complex
                ....
                */
                case ID_BAR_BUTTON:
                    DoBar(hwnd);
                    break;
                case ID_EXIT_BUTTON:
                    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, wparam, lparam);
                    break;
                case ID_OPEN_BUTTON:
                    OpenFile(hwnd);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This part is only getting more and more complex and ugly. Do you know any way to simplify it, perhaps something like the way I always see in many GUI libraries:

```
some_magic(some_object, message, callback);
```

Any simple advice will be a great help.

Comment: This is precisely why people use such GUI frameworks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MFC, ATL, WTL use map concept to define message-to-member mapping in developer friendly way. A macro conceals comparison of message/command/notification codes and respective member function is called on criteria satisfaction.

I hope this explains how it works. A set of `MAP_ENTRY` lines is supposed to look not that ugly.

```
#define MAP_ENTRY(message, callback) if(msg == message) return callback(wnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
// ...
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
  MAP_ENTRY(WM_INITDIALOG, OnInitDialog)
  MAP_ENTRY(WM_DESTROY, OnDestroy)
  MAP_ENTRY(WM_TIMER, OnTimer)
  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
LRESULT OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
  // ...
}
LRESULT OnDestroy(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
  // ...
}
LRESULT OnTimer(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
  // ...
}
```